# Parallel text with headers

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, parallel, parallel-texts

I use `scrbook` and have two chapter which are set as parallel text (with `\usepackage{parallel}` on opposing pages. The text for the chapter is `\include`d. How to  make headers on each page, such that the left page has the left text (german) header and the right page has the right text (english) header?

The code is

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      6.14in:9.21in,    
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    DIV=13,   
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \mainmatter 

 \chapter[Vorwort - Preface]{Vorwort für die Reihe 
            \vspace{10mm}
                         Preface to the Series}\label{vorwort} 
 \clearpage 
     \begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}  % must be capital P
         \ParallelLText{ german 
                        \Blindtext
                        }
         \ParallelRText{ english 
                        \lipsum
                        }
      \end{Parallel}

\clearpage 

\end{document}
```

But this produces and german/english header on the left page and nothing on the right one? What is wrong? What are the command to replace the short form of the header set by two headers left and right?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Your code example does not compile. Please provide a minimal _working_ example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The code now uses blindtext and lipsum in lieu of includes.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting with the MWE I found the simple answer: use `\markboth{leftHeader}{rightHeader}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      6.14in:9.21in,    
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    DIV=13,   
    fontsize=11pt,
}
\usepackage[german]{babel}  
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \mainmatter 

 \chapter[Vorwort - Preface]{Vorwort für die Reihe 
            \vspace{10mm}
            Preface to the Series}\label{vorwort} 

 \clearpage 
 \thispagestyle{myheadings}
 \markboth{Vorwort}{Preface}

     \begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}  % must be capital P
         \ParallelLText{ german 
                        \Blindtext
                        }
         \ParallelRText{ english 
                        \lipsum
                        }
      \end{Parallel}

\clearpage 

\end{document}
```

I appreciate the pressure to produce a MWE - it usually helps a lot to find an answer!